# Авторизация на сайте dnevnik.ru с помощью пакета request в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация, requests

При входе на сайт необходимо авторизоваться. Как я понял, сделав это надо сохранить куки и в дальнейшем использовать их? Как это реализовать? Мои наброски

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://login.dnevnik.ru/login', auth = ('log',   'pass'))
r = s.get('https://dnevnik.ru/user/')
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Разные сайты могут использовать разные механизмы для входа пользователей

Comment: ваш вариант не работает? В принципе все верно. Сначало авторизуетесь, потом забираете нужную страницу.

Comment: @jfs Допустим, я могу отправить через форму {'login':'log','password':'pass'}. Но сути это не меняет, куки не сохраняются, я не могу перейти на страницу '/user', так как я не авторизован. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: @jfs Лол, так и сделал, получилось. Я дурак или да?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил собственную проблему.

```
def main():
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.post('https://login.dnevnik.ru/login', data = {'login':'login', 'password':'pass'})
    r = s.get('https://dnevnik.ru/user')
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Верно, Session позволяет сохранить некоторые параметры между запросами, в том числе cookies, как явно показано в [примере из документации requests модуля](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects).